# What gotchas are there for existing sites to render properly in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, web

Now that IE8 is out, what are the gotchas that web developers are likely to encounter in their existing sites? Is there a list of "breaking" changes? Or is this thing "just going to work" with existing sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some great reference pages over on www.quirksmode.org. This site keeps a detailed record of the features supported by all major browsers, including IE8.

http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about a list of "breaking changes" but a couple of things I have noticed with testing with IE8.

1. It does break things
2. You must test your website both with compatibility mode on and off. The funny thing is that compatibility mode doesn't render the same as IE7 and sometimes it will work in IE7, and IE8 with compatibility mode off, but IE8 with compatibility mode on it won't work.bSo with IE8 coming about you essentially have 2 browsers in one to test